# _mm_packus_epi16 saturation issue

Tags: c++, c, x86, sse, simd

when i use _mm_packus_epi16, values less than zero are coming as zero but numbers higher than 127 are going to negative values.

According to this link, it should unsigned saturation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07ad1wx4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

But not happening

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
    __m128i result, resultHi, resultLo;
    //processing.....
    result = _mm_packus_epi16(resultLo, resultHi);
```

Comment: maybe you have to initialize resultHi and resultLo..

Comment: This should work as you expect - the packed values should all be in the range 0..255 - can you post some actual code that reproduces the problem? My guess is that you are just mis-interpreting the results.

Comment: there are values in resultHi and resultLo.
I jus want the 16bit values of resultHi and resultLo to get saturated to 8 bit unsigned int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that you are just misinterpreting the output data, e.g. displaying it as signed 8 bit rather than unsigned. Here is a demo program anyway, which may help to clarify things:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    __m128i resultLo = _mm_setr_epi16(800, 700, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100);
    __m128i resultHi = _mm_setr_epi16(0, -100, -200, -300, -400, -500, -600, -700);
    __m128i result = _mm_packus_epi16(resultLo, resultHi);
    printf("resultLo = %vhd\n", resultLo);
    printf("resultHi = %vhd\n", resultHi);
    printf("result   = %vu\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc -Wall -msse3 packus.c && ./a.out
resultLo = 800 700 600 500 400 300 200 100
resultHi = 0 -100 -200 -300 -400 -500 -600 -700
result   = 255 255 255 255 255 255 200 100 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
$
```

Comment: I agree with you, but what i am getting is weird.
I am trying to upload a snapshot of the debug output but SO is not letting me.

Answer (score 2):

Since `UnsignedSaturate` converts 16-bit signed integers to 8-bit unsigned integers it needs a way to deal with values that don't fit, thus values less than 0 (remember you're coming from a signed value) are clipped to 0 while values greater than 255 are clipped to 255.

If you have, let's say, a resulting value of 130 into an unsigned 8-bit char, that would be -126 if you interpret that data as a signed 8-bit char.

Since you're using `__m128i` to hold the results, you will have to do that conversion yourself (i.e. from signed to unsigned) unless you use some specific extension to SSE (e.g. Microsoft's `m128i_u8`).

In conclusion: **you're just interpreting the data wrong**.